# Can't view wifi networks after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04 GNOME

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

None of the wifi networks not shown in the list. 
Some of the troubleshooting steps done are:

sudo lshw - C network

---

```
Network DISABLED
Description :Wireless interface 
Product:RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/761678/edit) the question to include results for `rfkill list all`